# pfSense CARP seems to cause NIC issues

Tags: high-availability, pfsense, nic, carp

Within 12 hours of turning on HA we can't reach the webGUI, ping the pfSense machine, or have the pfSense machine ping anything. Prior to doing HA everything was working fine. After having this issue before, we did a fresh install/config and are experiencing the same problem with HA again.

Our setup is 2 pfSense 2.3 firewalls, with CARP VIPs on LAN and WAN. pfSync occurs on a dedicated interface (allowing all traffic to pass) via a crossover cable and the configuration sync occurs on our primary vlan. NAT is setup for all the vlans. Fail over itself works fine but for some reason we loose connectivity to at least one machine. After checking things and rebooting the machine, the next day it's down again.

We're at the point where we either get help in solving this issue or do without HA.

Additions: Nothing unusual in the logs

[Configuration Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XuQML.png)

Comment: It's definitely the CARP setup as once I deleted the CARP VIPs there were no issues. We've had to put this one up sooner than expected so we've abandoned the CARP failover for now.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out there must be some sort of hardware issue in the desktops we were using. It was failing even after we disabled CARP. Once we switched to using a server everything worked fine.